# hive partitioned and unpartitioned tables runtime and cpu time

Tags: mysql, database, hive, partition

I currently have a table below

```
create table flights(Year int, Month int, dayOfMonth int, dayOfWeek 
int, depTime int, CRSDepTime int, arrTime int, CRSArrTime int, 
uniqueCarrier string, flightNum int, tailNum int, actualElapsedTime 
int, CRSElapsedTime int, airTime int, arrDelay int, depDelay int, 
origin string, dest string, distance int, taxiIn int, taxiOut int, 
cancelled int, cancellationCode string, diverted int, carrierDelay 
int, weatherDelay int, NASDelay int, securityDelay int, 
lateAircraftDelay int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

and, I partitioned this table using month column, and comparing the CPU time and total time taken. I can see that CPU time decreased dramatically on partitioned table compared to unpartitioned table. However, for the total time taken, both are the same.

note : I am using the database that has 22 years of all flights in the past. so the amount of data is huge.

I want to know why CPU time decreased and total time are still same.

Comment: for which query?